# golang: what assembly instructions are available

Tags: go

I've got a program that I'm running on an ARM and I'm writing one function of it in assembly.  I've made good progress on this, although I've found it difficult sometimes to figure out exactly how to write certain instructions for go's assembler, for example, I didn't expect a right shift to be written like this:

MOVW    R3>>8, R3

Now I want to do a multiply and accumulate (MLA), according to this doc not all opcodes are supported, so maybe MLA isn't, but I don't know how to tell if it is or not.  I see mentions of MLA with regards to ARM in the golang repo, but I'm not really sure what to make of what I see there.

Is there anywhere that documents what instructions are supported and how to write them?  Can anyone give me any useful pointers?

Comment: Very surprised by the -1 on the question -- it's a sensible, clear question, and it's not something you can just look up in the manual.

Comment: Already asked and answered on the golang-nuts Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/6-qcvLnW7b4/bp9LCrTI2vcJ. Not sure if the OP posted both or simply scraped the question.

Comment: Oh, interesting, it's verbatim. Huh.

Comment: Huh, asker's one [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985294/ember-cli-with-testem) is [also on a forum](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-cli-with-testem/6309), also answered by SamLosAngeles with a quote from the forum.

Comment: No expert but seems OK; question issues aren't your fault. Given oddness involving this asker, copying, etc., the question might disappear, though.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit of a scrappy doc i wrote on [how to write ARM assembler](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JrxVxcG2JYPO-hTfIV-ZPwvnDetFiKElTj3BIEbHpO8/pub)

I wrote it from the point of view of an experienced ARM person trying to figure out how Go assembler works.

Here is an excerpt from the start.  Feel free to email me if you have more questions!

---

The Go assembler is based on the plan 9 assembler which is documented here.

http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/asm.html

Nice introduction to ARM

http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/index.html

Opcodes

http://simplemachines.it/doc/arm_inst.pdf

Instructions

- Destination goes last not first
- Parameters seem to be completely reversed
- May be condensed to 2 operands, so

  - ADD r0, r0, r1 ; [ARM] r0 <- r0 + r1
  - is written as
  - ADD r1, r0, r0
  - or
  - ADD r1, r0
- Constants denoted with '$' not '#'

Comment: Note that argument orders being reversed seem to be true for all assembly languages, not just ARM. If you're learning any assembly language AND using Go at the same time prepare to do a ton of legwork figuring out exactly how to translate example code into Go's assembler's soup of semi-ad hoc register names and reversed argument order. (E.G. a lot of example Intel code uses the register EAX which Go does not like)